# TextView value not being updated by the Service - Android GPS

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I have a  button that starts my DelayedMessageService. The service is very simple service because all it does is calculate the distance travelled by the user.  I want to display the total distance travelled  but the problem is it's not displaying the value in the TextView of my MainAcitivy.  Can someone please help me fix this issue. Here is my MainAcvity, Service, and activity_main.xml:

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String distanceStr;

    DelayedMessageService mDelayedMessageService;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        watchMileage();



        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DelayedMessageService.class);
                intent.putExtra(DelayedMessageService.EXTRA_MESSAGE,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.button_response));
                startService(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void watchMileage() {
        final TextView distanceView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                double distance = 0.0;
                if (mDelayedMessageService != null) {
                    distance = mDelayedMessageService.getMiles();
                }
                 distanceStr = String.format("%1$,.2f miles", distance);
                distanceView.setText(distanceStr);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    //Log.v("INOCRECTEA", distanceStr.toString());
}
```

//activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/button_text"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:onClick="onClick"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

  <TextView android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a variable called `mDelayedMessageService` but I don't see you initialize it in the snippet of code you provided so it is `null`. And then inside `watchMileage()` you do

```
if (mDelayedMessageService != null) {
      distance = mDelayedMessageService.getMiles();
}
```

Obviously, your `distance` will always be `0.0`.

Comment: Thanks @Renat Kaitmazov. where exactly do I iniatilise mDelayedMessageService for this to work?

Do i write mDelayedMessageService = new DelayedMessageService () inside the watchMileage() 

I thought this code already starts and iniatilise DelayedMessageService
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DelayedMessageService.class);
                intent.putExtra(DelayedMessageService.EXTRA_MESSAGE,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.button_response));
                startService(intent);

Comment: No. You should not initialise a service yourself. It is a system component and the system itself does everything for you. Here you used a so-called started service via `startService()` method. In order to get a reference to a service you need a so-called bind service. Here is the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: And one more thing to notice. The actual calculation of the distance is triggered only after a user clicks the button. You call `watchMileage()` right inside `onCreate()` before that calculation happens. When the user clicks that button you need to store your result so that you can show it next time.

Comment: I thought the bind service will only run your service while your acvitiy is in the foreground. I want to run my service in the background even if my activity is not present. How would I do that?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. A bind service works while an activity is in the foreground. But it is the only way to get a reference to a service.

Comment: One way is to use `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` if you are targeting devices with API >= 21.

Comment: Okay thanks @ Renat Kaitmazov instad of using AlarmManager or JobScheduler, can I use PeriodicTask?

Comment: You are welcome. I haven't worked with `PeriodicTask` so I cannot say if you can use it or not.

Comment: okay I will give it a go. thanks for your help and prompt reply